# Galaxy s 3 overheating seemingly out of nowhere

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, hardware, overheating

Phone is fairly new to me, I got it November or so. It's always worked just fine. Today I had it plugged in, walked into the other room for a few minutes and came back. Phone showed an error something like "Charging paused. system is too hot." So my Boyfriend told me to restart it and put in my extra battery (because I have two batteries for it). Did that, powered back up, was working on where in settings I could find the battery temperature and (less than 5 minutes)it told me something to the effect of "System overheating. all apps have been closed, phone can only be used for contacts". So I powered off, pulled out the battery, and now I'm nervous to try and turn it on again. 
Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm not rooted

Comment: I think there is no problem with the charger, but with the phone itself. This may happen when there are issue in the motherboard. If the problem persists, you should try contacting a repair shop to make it checked.

Comment: interesting... I used to have a tablet that gurgled and became very hot while charging.

Answer (score 0):

I had an S4 for a while and now have a Galaxy Note 4. My family has the S5 and S6, I believe, and all of them have gotten very hot while charging at one point or another, but not with an error.

Check to see if your charger reads 5V - 2A, which is what should be on the S3. You could try charging while the phone is off - just watch its temperature.

Comment: The charger I've been using for it IS a Samsung charger, it was given to me with the phone. The output however, reads 5.0v-0.7A. I don't know jack about chargers and the like. I tried a few others when I first got it, and this was the only charger that worked while it was on, so the battery didn't drain faster than it charged.
Is that what might have fried it?

Comment: I found a usb to wall port that says 5V-2A. It also is samsung brand. Any advice on how to know what USB cord to use with it?

Comment: I tried a USB cable with the port I found that had the right numbers on it. I don't know if the USB cord i used was bad, or if the port was bad, but the phone didn't do anything. I plugged it into the cord i was using (Because It drained the battery when it overheated. It was at 46%, and then I let it rest with the battery out and it told me 1% when I tried to power up to see if it was still overheating) and it showed me a warning triangle and a thermometer.

Comment: It starts flashing the triangle/thermometer as soon as I plug it in (even though it's not hot) and then starts getting hot after disconnected from the charger now.  I can't power up to check anything else because the overheat killed both my batteries.

Comment: @Amyautopsy I think there is no problem with the charger, but with the phone itself. This may happen when there are issue in the motherboard. If the problem persists, you should try contacting a repair shop to make it checked.

Comment: It is something called short circuit, easily repairable by a technician.